# How to Disable Tapping - Dell Inspiron 3521 - Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, mouse, touchpad, synaptics-touchpad

I have read many sets of directions on disabling mouse tapping.  There are no "touchpad settings" anywhere.  (Control panel -> mouse setting, Device Manager -> properties.)  I have gone through every menu, and checked for any other button that appear for each menu item - repeatedly.  The only item in the Device Manager is "Mice and Other Pointing Devices" -> "PS/2 Compatible Mouse."  The driver is version 6.3.9600.17393 6/21/2006.  If I try to update the driver Windows reports that the best driver is already installed.

Maybe I need a 3rd party driver.  There is no way to change the sensitivity or anything related to tapping.  There is a constant problem where the computer says I tapped when I didn't, and doesn't recognize a tap when I want one.  This has been an extremely frustrating feature of this computer for then entire time I have owned it.  I want tapping disabled, which is exactly what I did on my previous computer.

BTW - This DOES NOT exist on my system:  "Click on the little up arrow on the right hand side of your start menu (your open applications), right click on the little icon that looks like a touch pad (large rectangle on top of 2 smaller rectangles)."

Also, I have gone through every single category in the Device Manager (USB devices, System devices, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found "Dell Touchpad Driver" at Dell.com, after entering my computer model there.  It's dated Jan 9, 2019.  I installed the driver, and rebooted.  Now when I go to Control Panel, "mouse" in search box, "Mouse Properties," there is a "Click to change DellTouchpad Settings."  This opens up a custom program, with many options (touch pressure,  palm rejection, etc.)   Problem solved.

I don't know whether Dell has finally solved this serious problem, or if there was a previous Dell driver that did this that I didn't find.

In any event, this computer came with Windows 8 pre-installed, and there was absolutely no way to change anything about the TouchPad.